# Retrieve a agenda view of days with scheduled or appointed tasks

Tags: org-mode

I could get a:

1,  org-agenda-day-view
2,  org-agenda-week-view
3,  org-agenda-month-view
4,  org-agenda-year-view

How could I get a real agenda which filter the days with scheduled tasks

I collect all the scheduled tasks in ticker.org but unable to read them all in a calendar view

my `org-agenda-file` in `.emacs.d/init.el`

```
(setq org-agenda-files '("~/GTD/inbox.org"
                         "~/GTD/gtd.org"
                         "~/GTD/tickler.org"
                         "~/GTD/today.org"
                         "~/GTD/two_minutes.org"
                         "~/GTD/next_action.org"))
```

Comment: do you have the file or folder included in the variable `org-agenda-files`?

Comment: Yes, I appended it to the question. @manandearth I am trying to get a calendar which only display the scheduled day.